# "What time?" instead of "What day?"

Tags: colloquialisms, dates

I was talking with a friend about an event that was going to happen in the future. He asked me "What time?" referring, as I discovered after a while, to the day this event was going to happen.

I didn't know that "time" could be used instead of "day". I thought it could be used instead of "hour", or "minute", asking **for** the time of the event. But my friend meant to ask me the day.

Is this common usage? If two people are talking about something in the future, can one ask the other "what time", meaning the day of the event, not the actual time?

Answer (score 2):

No, I wouldn't use it that way. *Time* here refers to a specific time, and if I were asked the same question, I would assume the other person knew the *date* and was only interested in finding out the *time* of the meeting.

Answer (score 1):

The question "What time?" could refer to the day of an event. One definition *Merriam-Webster* provides for time is:

> the point or period when something occurs : occasion

*Encyclopædia Britannica* defines time as "a measured or measurable period." A [solar] day is a measured period and a fundamental unit of time, therefore the question "What time?," could refer to the date of an event.

It would, however, have been more appropriate for the question to use the word "when," or for the asker to have requested the specific unit of time (date) he desired to know.

Comment: Oh ok, it is used that way then...is it widely used? I have been in North America for a year and a half now and this was the first time I heard it.

Comment: I live in "the South" (not that that necessarily means anything). I have heard that before, however I do agree that it is unusual. I completely understand your confusion, as it would make far more sense for the asker to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming it, I was really stunned by this new "way" of asking the day :)

Comment: I think this explanation is unhelpful and acts only to confuse the issue.  Strictly speaking, you are correct but the most common use of "Time" implies a higher degree of precision, whereas day is less precise - one seventh of 168 hours.  "I'll see you next Thursday", leaves 23:59:59 of ambiguity, "I'll see you at eleven next Thursday" gives you a 50:50 chance of seeing your friend, while "Shall we meet at 14:35 next Thursday" defines a precise point in the space / time continuum with only 59 seconds of ambiguity: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should...